# _userManager.GetUserAsync(User) returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to check a users email confirmation status after login and then direct them accordigly.

Based on these two threads:

[ASP.NET Core Identity - get current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751616/asp-net-core-identity-get-current-user)

[How get current user in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

I tried this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
    var thisUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(currentUser);
    if(thisUser.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Task/Index.cshtml");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ConfirmEmail");
    }
}
```

And also this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{   
    var thisUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    if(thisUser.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Task/Index.cshtml");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ConfirmEmail");
    }
}
```

From inside controller but `thisUser` is always null.

How do I check on logon that their email is confirmed and re-direct appropriately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem to your approach, which is true for `Membership` and `Identity`: they're based on `cookies`. Cookies can only be read if they are sent by the client.

So, this is your flow:

1. Set cookie
2. Read cookie

This is wrong as explained above. Your flow should either be:

1. Set cookie
2. Redirect somewhere
3. Read cookie (which now was sent by the client)

OR

1. Set cookie
2. Read data from wherever it's stored basing on the `email` you already have

Answer (score 0):

I had email in model so I just looked it up directly in database.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

    var user = _context.Users.Single(x => x.Email == model.Email);

    if(user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Task/Index.cshtml");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ConfirmEmail");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio):

> Identity is enabled by calling [UseAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authappbuilderextensions.useauthentication). UseAuthentication
>   adds authentication [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to the request pipeline.

So, inside the `Configure` method, if you forgot setting up

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

you will get the same result without any error.