# Does Indentiy in ASP.NET MVC core provide an easy way to access the UserId from any page ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Or do I need to set up Sessions in ASP.NET and get the user ID and pass it around manually like... ?

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        //Save UserId in session
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserIdKey", "123");
        ViewData["UserId"] = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserIdKey");
```

....

Comment: Via the `UserManager` would seem to be the way in .net Core - see [ASP.NET Core Identity - get current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751616/asp-net-core-identity-get-current-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Extension**

```
    public static class IdentityExtension
    {
        public static string GetId(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            Claim claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            return claim.Value;
        }
    }
```

**Example**

```
User.Identity.GetId()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have injected a [`UserManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0), as of 2.1 [you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_GetUserId_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_):

```
string userid = _userManager.GetUserId(userPrincipal);
```

Where `userPrincipal` can be provided by the [ControllerBase.User Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-2.0).