# asp.net core trying to select objects that contains exact id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to pull out of database objects where current user Id is in list of those objects.

My model:

```
 public class Procedure
 {
   ...
   public IList<User> Lawyers{ get; set; }
   ...
 }
```

And in controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyProcedures()
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var procedures = context.Procedures.Where(x => x.Lawyers.Contains(user));
        return View(procedures);
    }
```

This only selects one object.

EDIT:
Problem is in my User class, it takes only one Id from Procedure and that is why its showing my only one (last added). Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Will you include a screenshot of the Procedure table's records, so we could verify if there's more than 1 record there for your user? Also highlight which one is your UserId

Comment: contains same object relies on they're really same objects. so you could try this instead, 
```cs
var procedures = context.Procedures.Where(x => x.Lawyers.Any(y => y.Id == user.Id));
```

Comment: You probably have link table to link `Procedure` and `Lawyers`, you can try to query from there: `context.LawyerProcedures.Where(link => link.LawyerId == user.Id).Select(link => link.Procedure)`

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote will work if you have icomparable or something implemented that can tell that a lawyer is “the” user if user id matches.

Without that you would need to do lawyers.Any(x=> x.UserId == user.UserId)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something, which user ??

Either pass something *into your function signature* or get it from `HTTPContex`t you need to get the user you want to find

If you are using ASP core its bit different from the old ways

First this:

---

```
var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

---

And now..

```
// make sure you can access/inject it if you want
// private.. _httpContextAccessor 
// then in your action

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyProcedures()
{
    // again make sure you can access the context _httpContextAccessor
    var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var procedures = context.Procedures.Where(x => x.Lawyers.Contains(userId).FirstOrDefault());

    //... fill in whatever logic you want.. 

    return View(parnice);
}
```

---

**Update 2 based on question/comments:**

### Do this in two Steps

1. Step 1: Get the Current User (with `claims` or `HTTPContext` as shown below), for e.g. `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;`
2. Step 2: Using the user, find all the *related* Lawyers etc. `context.Procedures.Where(x => x.Lawyers.Contains(userId)`

Make sure to register HttpContextAccessor in your startup... double check this.. to register in your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

In the *original* Core version, I have to double check if it changed now, assuming your code is inside an MVC controller:

```
public class YourController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
```

Now, since you have the `Controller` base class, you can get the `IClaimsPrincipal` from the `User` property

```
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
```

You can check the claims directly (without a round trip to the database):

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User); // Get user id:
```

---

To your second comment, you can get either the UserId or UserName

```
     //  user's userId    
     var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) 
     //  user's userName
     var userName =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
```

A nice [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751842/6085193) for you hope it helps :)

Comment: My User class is inherited from IdentityUser class. I'm using asp.net core mvc and entity framework core.
`var procedures = context.Procedures.Where(x => x.Lawyers.Contains(userId).FirstOrDefault());` 
shows error that cannot convert string to User

I've injected `private readonly AppDbContext context;` and in construtor as well. I'm just looking here to get Procedures which have list of Users as a Lawyers and return to View only those Procedures that are linked to currently logged User.

Comment: you also need the current users `HTTPContext`or the `claims principal`  to get the current user