# How to get User information from auth_token supplied by Auth0 tenant in PKCE flow

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, auth0, pkce

I have just successfully implemented the [PKCE Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce) from my Cordova Ionic5 mobile app which then uses the auth_token to authorize against my .NET Core 3.1 Web Api.

The problem is that I cannot access the user information from my .NET Core Web Api:
name, email, etc.

I really need to know “who” the user is which just authenticated. Can you please help?

**The PKCE flow**
[image]
**Code in my `Startup.cs`**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = _configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
                options.Audience = _configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
            });

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751616/asp-net-core-identity-get-current-user

Comment: Nope, I've tried everything there but my User is always NULL!\

Comment: Did you call app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization()? If you forget to use those middlewares, token won't be parsed and User will be null

Comment: yes, I also update my question Startup.cs to reflect this

Comment: Are you sending the token with API requests? They must have `Authorization: Bearer $token` header. Watch requests from your browser's developer console and make sure requests include the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the access token wont have user information like *name* and *email*.

Here's an example access token for a default authentication to an Auth0 tenant (using PKCE flow with SPA).

```
{
  "iss": "https://example.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|REDACTED",
  "aud": [
    "REDACTED",
    "https://example.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1599312415,
  "exp": 1599398815,
  "azp": "REDACTED",
  "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

Your app should also receive an `id_token`, which might look like the following (assuming the request to `/authorize` includes the openid, profile, and email scopes).

```
{
  "nickname": "joe.blogs",
  "name": "joe.blogs@example.com",
  "picture": "REDACTED",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-04T10:21:07.315Z",
  "email": "joe.blogs@example.com",
  "email_verified": false,
  "iss": "https://example.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|REDACTED",
  "aud": "REDACTED",
  "iat": 1599312415,
  "exp": 1599348415,
  "nonce": "REDACTED"
}
```

So you've got a couple options to get the name and email to your back-end API.

1. In your app, parse the id_token JWT to get the name and email, and then explicitly pass these fields to your back-end API.
2. You *can* enrich access token with name and email via [Auth0 rules](https://auth0.com/docs/rules). Here is an example rule to add `email` to the access token (note: untested):

```
function addAttributes(user, context, callback) {
  context.accessToken.email = user.email;
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

see docs for Auth0 [context object](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/context-object) and [user object](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/user-object-in-rules) to see what you've got access to...

My thoughts are that option #1 is better approach because; a) I don't like to have PII in access tokens, and b) relying on access tokens to have information like name and email can lead to issues down the track (e.g. what happens if your back-end API also needs to get called with Auth0 M2M tokens that don't have this info).

Finally in your .NET app, you can get the information you need by parsing the JWT in the Authorization HTTP header. Let me know if you need more information about this part (as I can help with this as well if needed)... just assuming the main issue is that you don't have the required user information in the JWT access token (which you should now if you follow my instructions)...

Comment: Actually the solution was to add the claims to the auth_token. This is done by setting a rule in Auth0. Once I set the rule I was able to see my claims in the auth_token.

Comment: Good to hear you solved the issue. Given this was one of my suggested options (see option #2 in answer), would you consider releasing the bounty that was on the initial question?

Comment: hey buddy, sorry but the bounty expired... I sincerely apologize...