# How to get current user in ASP.NET core with IdentityServer4 in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, identityserver4

Created out of the box app `dotnet new angular --auth Individual`. It works fine.

Now I want to upgrade it a little. Say I want to show weather forecast for the user location. Normally (when I implement OAuth with WebApi myself) I would retrieve user from data base when application requests OAuth token and then inject Claim say "UserID"="1001".. And when user clicks Fetch Data - I would retrieve that userid and the location in the **controller** and return data relevant to that user..

**How do I do that with IdentityServer4 - getting user in a controller?**

*Startup.cs*

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            ...
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

. . .

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

*HttpContext.User and Claims has no meaningful information..*
[image]

Comment: This question has already been answered here :
[ASP.NET Core Identity - get current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751616/asp-net-core-identity-get-current-user/38751842#38751842)

Comment: you saved me !  :) thank you.. I tried UserManager.GetUserId but it returns null... I havent seen User.FindFirst anywhere or i missed it..

Answer (score 1):

Currently with asp.net core 5.0 and identityServer4 this works inside a controller:

```
this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

and this returns null:

```
userManager.GetUserId(User);
```