# How to get logged user data in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC (.NET 5)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web project, I used default created Single User Account generated template for user management. I have applied the migration and it's working fine as expected. I need to get logged user, in .NET 5 Single User Account template `AccountController` was not visible. I tried following code outside the controller, it's giving `null`.

```cs
public class UserService  
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string GetUser()
    {
       return _context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see sample code at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751842/3728901 (maybe, ASP.NET Core 1, 2, or 3)

Focus at

```cs
public class MyController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
```

```cs
var id = _userManager.GetUserId(User); // Get user id:
```

or other way

```cs
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

//class constructor
public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

and

```cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var email = user.Email;
```

Because this question related .NET 5 therefore I don't consider the question is duplicated. Let's me know or revise small details if has minor changes in .NET 5.